# Windows 11 File Copy produces 0 byte file and then prompts a Replace or Skip Files dialog

Tags: dialog

I have just got a new PC with Windows 11 and I have come across a problem and I can't seem to fix it.

I have explorer window open, I copy a file then try and paste into a new location on a mapped network drive (Buffalo NAS) or drag/drop the file to a mapped network drive (Buffalo NAS)
Windows 11 creates a 0 byte file on the mapped drive and then prompts "Replace or Skip Files dialog".
I then have to choose replace the file in the destination to complete the file copy/move.
!! I do not have a previous copy already in the new location if anyone asks.

Example,

1. create a new file in the c:\users\Peter\Documents\Monday\hjkhgjsgsk.txt (or any other name)
2. drag the file to Z:\Documents\Tuesday.
3. Windows 11 creates an empty 0 byte file called hjkhgjsgsk.txt
4. Windows 11 puts up the dialog "Replace or Skip Files"
5. I have to choose "Replace the file in the destination" to complete the file copy/move etc

Have I got a a setting wrong some where?

FYI: I have no problem drag/copy betweek local drives or from the mapped drive to a local drive. It's just local -> mapped drive

Also no other PC's (Win 10) in the house is having this problem, just my new Win 11 PC

Thanks

Comment: Windows 11 enforces SMB V3 .  Is your NAS SMB V1?

Comment: @John: Otherwise nothing will work at all.

Comment: This could be a permissions problem. How is your user defined in the NAS? Could you please in Explorer, click Network, right-click the NAS share, select Properties, tab Security, click Advanced and take a screenshot of the dialog, then upload it and share the link with us.

Comment: Yes. I viewed a 0 byte file as nothing if the NAS saw a failed attempt,